# Условие "если переменная больше одного числа, но меньше другого"

Tags: javascript

Как записать такое условие в Javascript ? Если `x` больше 5, но меньше 20, то ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле тут два условия:

1. `x` > 5
2. `x` < 20

Союз *но* в значении *и*.

Оператор Логическое "И" в javascript обозначается как `&&`

Итоговая запись будет выглядеть так:

```
x > 5 && x < 20
```

Либо более похоже на привычную запись неравенства: 5 < `x` < 20

```
5 < x && x < 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Не мог все найти , но вроде так будет работать ;)

```
(x>5 && x<20)
```